# Is there a way to add extra attributes to a built-in function in python?

Tags: python, function

Suppose I have a function and want to add extra attributes to it e.g. a 'last inputted' attribute to a print statement. *This function would be able to take over all existing functionality & some extra functionality.*

My idea was to make a function that would have the exact same functionality as a print statement but also be able to remember the last thing outputted.

I made this..

```
last_mes = ""
def pprint(message, **kwargs):
    global last_mes
    print(message, **kwargs)
    last_mes = message
```

I don't think this is the best way of doing it though. **Is there an optimum way of doing it?**

Comment: Yes that's achievable. Search for Method Overriding or Method Overloading in python and that shall do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no perfect way, but you could at least avoid polluting the global namespace by attaching the extra data to the function itself:

```
def pprint(message, **kwargs):
    print(message, **kwargs)
    pprint.last_mes = message
pprint.last_mes = ""
```

Other solutions include a singleton callable class instance:

```
class _StatefulPprint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_mes = ""
    def __call__(self, message, **kwargs):
        print(message, **kwargs)
        self.last_mes = message
pprint = _StatefulPprint()
# Optionally remove class to remove definition from view:
del _StatefulPprint
```

or use a closure maker:

```
def make_pprint():
    last_mes = ""
    def pprint(message, **kwargs):
        nonlocal last_mes
        print(message, **kwargs)
        last_mes = message
    return pprint
pprint = make_pprint()
del make_pprint  # Optional
```

The closure makes it impractical for you to access `last_mes` outside `pprint` though, so for this specific case (where doing so is almost certainly a design goal) it won't work.

Last option I'll give is the hackiest one (which shares the weakness of the closure, and adds one more, but is the simple to write); hide it in a mutable default parameter:

```
def pprint(message, *, _last_mes_store=[""], **kwargs):
    print(message, **kwargs)
    _last_mes_store[0] = message
```

The extra problem that adds is that if the caller actually passes `_last_mes_store` by keyword, you don't update the "function static" default parameter you intended to.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you'd like to overload the built-in print function so that it has extra parameters, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/04/27/underscoring-or-dunder-scoring-the-importance-of-native-type-methods-in-python/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).